# Intersection of nested compact sets

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Consider a topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$, and a sequence of sets $(K_n)_{n\in\omega}$, such that $(\forall n\in\omega)(K_n\text{ is compact})$, and $(\forall m<n)(K_m\supset K_n)$. Is it true that $\cap_{n\in\omega}K_n\neq\emptyset$?

Answer (score 9):

As pointed out elsewhere you need to assume the $K_n$ are all non-empty. However, that assumption is not strong enough: under the cofinite topology on $\Bbb{R}$, [every subset of $\Bbb{R}$ is compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468889/how-is-every-subset-of-the-set-of-reals-with-the-finite-complement-topology-comp). So if you take $K_n = \{n, n + 1, n + 2, \ldots\}$, you get a counter-example to your claim.

If you assume $(X, {\cal T})\,$ is Hausdorff, your claim holds. (If $\bigcap_n K_n\,$ were empty, the sets $K_1 \setminus K_n\,$ would be open, because of Hausdorffness, and would cover $K_1$. Hence a finite subset of these open sets would cover $K_1$, implying that the $K_n$ are eventually all empty).

All the above argument relies on is that the $K_i$ are all closed. So it works if we take that as an assumption or if we assume that $X$ is a [$KC$-space](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/KC-space), one in which all compact subsets are closed.

Comment: We can use a weaker assumption: https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000100 For example, the one point compactification of the rationals has this property but isn't T_2.

Comment: @StevenClontz: thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: If the assumption $K_m \supset K_n$ is a strict inclusion, non emptiness follows.

Comment: @chi: not so: read the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @RobArthan the point is, if $K_m = \{\}$ then you can't possibly have $K_m \supsetneq K_n$.

Comment: That's a good point, but the result is stronger to assume $\subset$ allows equality, with the caveat that sets are nonempty.

Comment: @chi: if you mean non-emptiness of all the $K_n$ follows, then you are right, although I preferred the more general reading of $\subset$ allowing equality. I thought you meant non-emptiness of the intersection.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: I see now that chi's commment was unclear. See my second response to it

Comment: Indeed my comment was misleading. I meant the emptiness of $K_n$, and I forgot that the thesis was also about non emptiness (of the intersection). I was focusing on the part "you need to assume that $K_n$ are all nonempty", and did not realize the ambiguity.

Comment: @chi: OK. No worries! We are all agreed now, I think.

Comment: Perhaps you should mention in your answer that spaces in which all compact sets are closed are known as *KC-spaces*. And of course the claim is true if all $K_n$ are assumed to be closed ...

Comment: @PaulFrost: I have done as you suggested. Thanks for improving the answer.